# Javascript + HTML5 localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

So I'm searching for a good crash course on localstorage and interacting with it in Javascript. I want to build a to-do list webapp with some extra functionality but it would be just for 1 user. I don't want to mess with php/mysql and have the server doing anything. Links to tutorials would be best :-D

Answer (score 18):

Here's a crash crash course I found very useful. It explains a bunch of HTML5 concepts, including localStorage, video tag, offline websites, forms, locations, canvas, and more.

http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html

Answer (score 10):

There is the offical documentation:

http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/

For a quick demo with code: http://html5demos.com/storage also more html5 demos at the root of that site.

Note there are also things like the [YUI 2 Storage Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/storage/) which abstract the storage for you (HTML 5, Google Gears, SWF) depending on what the browser supports:

> The Storage Utility provides a
>   mechanism for storing significant
>   amounts of textual data, client-side,
>   whether or not your browsers supports
>   the proposed HTML 5 Storage
>   specification.

Comment: Since HTML5 isn't everywhere yet, appreciate the abstraction layer recommendation for better web app support (Update: YUI has moved to [version 3](http://yuilibrary.com/)).  There is also an [older hack](http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html) that has its share of warts but might be useful with older browsers.

Comment: [jQuery's abstraction](http://www.jquerysdk.com/api/jQuery.localStorage) falls back to cookies.

Answer (score 3):

No personal experience but I did come across this link today:  http://www.w3avenue.com/2010/05/07/html5-unleashed-tips-tricks-and-techniques/

Which links to this:  http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-learning-about-html5-local-storage/

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

This small tutorial/code-snippet helped me to get started.

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/06/localstorage/

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend one of the other questions asked here about how to store objects in localStorage. It helped me a lot as I am implementing a code editor that can store multiple files and last state of the user.

[The stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)
Both answers posted are very valuable.

Some things to take into consideration:

- When do you store data, after each key pressed or after some other specific action/event?
- Use a temporary Javascript data structure or only interact with localStorage directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Store Data

//Syntax 
localStorage.setItem(Key,Value);
```

[Demo](http://qaify.com/blog/web-storage-in-html5-with-localstorage-and-sessionstorage-example/)