# appear the notification only one time without using cookie

Tags: jquery

this code will popup a shadow box for the visitor once the page load,
i want to make it to appear only one time to the visitor without using the cookie,how?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
tb_show("قبل أن تبدأ","thick.php?height=300&width=300", "");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use a cookie, you will have to use some mechanism to keep record whether the visitor has seen the message or not.  Could be a database or file on your server.

The modern alternative to cookies is [local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800238/javascript-html5-localstorage)