# Is it possible to save data to sqlite using flash player plugin rather then AIR?

Tags: sqlite, air, local-storage, flash

We have a flash web app. we thought to use local storage to enhance performance and responsiveness. LSO falls short to sqlite. AIR is too far on the roadmap for us productwise, therefore wanted to ask if the flash player had evolved to include sqlite local storage from the browser like HTML5 has access to...
cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to go through JS I think you are on the right track.

See: [Javascript + HTML5 localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800238/javascript-html5-localstorage)