# Best way to store data from user

Tags: javascript, storage, local-storage

I am creating browser extension, which react on user clicks. When user click, it generates xpath, value, hostname etc. Until user doesn't click final "send to server's DB" I want store this data locally. I want structure like that:

```
  action1:
    xpath: myVal1
    value: myVal2
    hostname: myVal3

  action2:
    xpath: myVal4
    value: myVal5
    hostname: myVal6

  action3:
    xpath: myVal7
    value: myVal8
    hostname: myVal9
```

I think the best actual way to do this is localStorage, but I don't know how to make something like that:

```
  action1.xpath = 'myNewPath'
  action2.value = 'myOtherValue'
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript + HTML5 localstorage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800238/javascript-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to store a customer:

```
localStorage.setItem("customer", customerInput.value);
```

You provide the name under which to store your data, in the above case `"customer"`, and the variable to store, in this case it's a value from a textfield.

To retrieve these values on whatever page you like use:

```
var localStorageCustomerValue = localStorage.getItem("customer");
```

And if you don't need this data anymore you use:

```
localStorage.removeItem("customer");
```

to remove it from localstorage