# How tin-can-api works offline?

Tags: javascript, tin-can-api

I am creating the ebook with some activities like quiz, puzzles using HTML5, CSS, JavaScript and Jquery. How to add Tin-Can into it. It should tract the action of reader and work offline.

As mention in Tin-Can API document [API Doc](http://tincanapi.com/overview/), it works online and offline. How it works offline?

As I understand Actor, Verb and Object statement has to store locally in log and send to LRS when its connected to LRS. Am I correct?

If Yes, How to maintain the log of Actor, Verb and Object statement locally?

If i am wrong, How its works offline and how to maintain the Actor, Verb and Object statements of reader?

Answer (score 3):

The mechanism for Tin Can to enable offline tracking is the [timestamp property](http://tincanapi.com/2013/08/22/deep-dive-roundup/?utm_source=tincanapi_com&utm_medium=stack_overflow&utm_term=andrew&utm_content=blog&utm_campaign=deep_dive_roundup?pmc=em-1). This enables you to record not just when data was stored, but when the learning experience actually happened so that statements can be stored and transferred to the LRS later when a connection is available.

As Tin Can is a specification to support interoperable communication between learning technologies, the exact mechanism for storing the data doesn't matter. So long as you send the data in the right way when you get a connection, the LRS will be able to receive that data, however it was stored prior to sending.

Now, whilst that technically answers your question, I imagine that "you can store it however you like" may not be a helpful answer if you're looking for one way, any way, to store the data rather than being in a situation of having lots of options and wanting to choose the Tin Can conformant option from that list.

I recommend that your next steps are for you to ask (or search for) a more generic question about data storage on your particular platform e.g. "[How do I store data on android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)" or "[How can I use JavaScript local storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800238/javascript-html5-localstorage)" as this particular technical challenge is in no way specific to Tin Can.

I hope that helps!