# How to save the data for browser closing and system power shutdown in PHP projects?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How to save the data for browser closing and system power shutdown in PHP projects

Comment: I guess **cookies** are what you are looking for..

Comment: Any other option? or please provide the references link.

Comment: you mean google.com?

Comment: no. I just asked any other option to find the browser close in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you can use `cookies`, some useful info here:

[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery/1458728#1458728)

Another option is `localStorage`:

[Javascript + HTML5 localstorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800238/javascript-html5-localstorage)

This topic can help you to choose, what to use:

[Local Storage vs Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)