Remembering dark mode between pages in local storage
I have this script toggle dark mode specified in my css but can't figure out how to make the dark mode stay on between pages.
Thanks ahead!
html:
    <img onclick="darkmode()" id="darktoggledesktop" src="media/darktoggle.svg" alt="">
    <script>
        function darkmode() {
          var element = document.body;
          element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
        }
    </script>
    <script>
        function menufunction() {
          var x = document.getElementById("mobilemenuopen");
          if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
          }
        }
        </script>

css:
.dark-mode {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    transition: 0.4s;
  }

I tried following similar threads here but can't seem to get this work.

Did you forget to add the code concerning the local storage?

you answered your own question ... in local storage

When you do get it to work (as you state, using (localStorage)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API]) then your next question will be how to stop the FOUC.  If using javascript, make sure your code that reads from localstorage and sets the class is immediately after the <body> tag.  Also, remove the transition if setting on load.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800238/javascript-html5-localstorage (off-topic for SO but includes some localStorage tutorial links)

As you mentioned you can do this using the localStorage. If you don't know how to use it you can read more about it here.
For this specific example, here's a working dark switch toggle script, which uses the localStorage to store a user's preference on page load.
<img onclick="toggleDarkMode()" id="darktoggledesktop" src="media/darktoggle.svg" alt="">
<script>
    // Function to toggle dark mode and save preference in localStorage
    function toggleDarkMode() {
        let element = document.body;
        element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
        if (element.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
            localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "enabled");
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "disabled");
        }
    }

    // Function to load dark mode preference on page load
    function loadDarkModePreference() {
        let darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
        if (darkMode === "enabled") {
            document.body.classList.add("dark-mode");
        }
    }

    // Load dark mode preference when the page loads
    window.onload = loadDarkModePreference;
</script>
<script>
    function menufunction() {
        let x = document.getElementById("mobilemenuopen");
        if (x.style.display === "block") {
            x.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            x.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
</script>


Ohhh, w3schools - controversial...

Feels a bit GPT-esk to me though

@fdomn-m Why controversial? I'm sorry if it's not liked to be seen, but I learned a lot from their pages. What's the problem with this?

@DarkBee How come? Cause I commented my code and named a function weirdly?

Because it's known for its low quality, bad practices and wrong information, even after it was refactored and updated

Alright, feel free to give me a better link and I'll add it. As said, personally it has helped me a lot.

Always MDN or the specification. The var in var darkMode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode"); is an example for the bad practices. You shouldn't be using var for almost 10 years now.

TBH: it now has some good beginner information / tutorials.  There was a long time it was just plain wrong (not even just incorrect or out dated) - they did make a huge update a while back, but still has the occasional issue or out dated information (as example above).  Hence: controversial (rather than a blanket "don't use w3schools")
